# Convergence in distribution and continuity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Convergence in distribution of a sequence of RV requires >$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n(x)=F(x)$

> for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ in wich $F$ is continous.

I was told that the constant random variables  $1/n$ will not converge in distribution if we want convergence at every point. But why is this the case? We know that  $1/n$ goes to zero when n goes to $\infty$ so that also in $x=0$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n(x)=F(x)$. Why is this not the case?

Comment: if you have $F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}x\mathbb{1}_{x\leq n}$, i.e. a constant function's distribution function, this converges pointwise to $0$, but $0$ is not a distribution as it doesn't satisfy $F(\infty) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the CDF's don't converge to the CDF of $0$ at $x=0$.

To see this, for any $n$, let $F_n(x)$ be the CDF of the constant random variable $\color{blue}{1/n}$. Also, let $F(x)$ be the CDF of the constant random variable $\color{blue}{0}$. Then for all $n$, we have $$F_n(0) = P(\color{blue}{1/n} \le 0) = 0,$$ but $$F(0)=P(\color{blue}{0}\le 0)=1.$$

Hence $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} F_n(0)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}0=0\color{red}{\ne} F(0).$$

Comment: Ok thank you  But what is the difference w.r.t the other x's?

Comment: If $x\ne 0$, then you can show as an exercise that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}F_n(x)= F(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. But uf we take $F_\infty don't we get  $$F_\infty(0) = P(\color{blue}{1/\infty} \le 0) = 0,$$?

Comment: If $\color{blue}{1/\infty}=\color{blue}{0}$, then wouldn't be $0$, it'd be $1$, since probability of $\color{blue}{0}$ being $\le 0$ is $1$.

Comment: Ok thank you. I meant one. But apart from what you mentioned, why is what I write weong? Thank you

Comment: Your $F_{\infty}(0)$ is not part of the sequence $(F_n(0))$, which only applies to positive integers $n$. So we can't say that the limit is $1$.